# How do I pass a member function template as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a member funtion like this:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  static void bar(const Args&... args)
  {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

And I want to pass it as a template parameter to a member function like this:

```cpp
class Example
{
public:
  template<typename... Args, typename T> // <- ???
  void doStuff(const Args&... args)
  {
    T(args...);
  }
};
```

I have tried multiple things here already, but the one that seemed the most promising was this:

```cpp
class Example
{
public:
  template<typename... Args, typename C, void (C::*F)(Args&...)>
  void doStuff(const Args&... args)
  {
    (C::F)(args...);
  }
};
```

Whilst troubleshooting I thought maybe it's because I got the function signature of bar wrong, so I changed the template of doStuff to this:

```cpp
template<typename... Args, typename C, void (C::*F)(const Args&...)>
```

Which didn't seem to help.

I suspect it is because I don't define, the template of parameter F, but I don't know how to add that.
Or maybe I could get around this all together by passing a lambda as an attribute to doStuff. I didn't try that yet though, and would idealy not want to have to resort to that.

EDIT 2:

Here is a minimum reproducable example:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  static void bar(const Args&... args)
  {
    /* code */
  }
};

class Example
{
public:
  template<typename... Args, typename C, void (C::*F)(Args&...)>
  void doStuff(const Args&... args)
  {
    (C::F)(args...);
  }
};

class SomeClass
{
public:
  Example ex {};

  template<typename... Args>
  void someFunc(const Args&... args)
  {
    ex.doStuff<Args..., Foo, &Foo::bar>(args...);
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomeClass sc {};
  sc.someFunc("Some ", "Arguments ", "Here");
  return 0;
}
```

I know, I know, I rushed the question sry

Comment: Why don't you want do use a lambda? It is the idiomatic solution and much simpler than passing member function pointers. (And also just as fast if that's what you are worried about)

Comment: please post a [mcve]. I mean its all there but you must have the code where you try to instantiate the template somewhere, an answer will have to include it too, so why not include it in the question...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I also realized I forgot a entry point and instantiation of the template in the post and updated it

Comment: now I am a little confused. You tried different ways to write the template, but you didnt actually try to instantiate them? I mean that `sc.someFunc("Some ", "Arguments ", "Here");` doesnt work is not related to how you write the template

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Luh0 `Foo` doesn't have any method call `doSomething` so `foo.doSomething<Args..., Foo, &Foo::bar>(args);` is wrong.

Comment: @chrysante Oh interesting. I thought, they come with some performance deficit. Then I'll use lambdas

Comment: @Luh0 Also you haven't used `Example` anywhere in your program. This question is not clear at all.

Comment: @Jason I edited in that part real quick, and It's wrong I'm fixing that right now.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah I get that give me second

Comment: @Luh0 Also don't forget to show how you mean to use `Example` class. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on [some site](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

Comment: Generally you should not **assume** the performance cost of any language construct or feature. Either measure or try to understand what is happening behind the scenes, for example by using godbolt.org. As a rule of thumb write the code that *works* and if it's too slow then profile and optimize.

Comment: @Luh0 See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080744/12002570) where i've shown how to solve your problem. I've also attached a [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xhEM7oYs1).

Comment: Since your member function is static, it doesn’t matter that it’s a member function.  You should simplify that aspect out of the question if that’s the intent.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have to use the `(Classtype::*)()` syntax with static member function. Static member functions are treated as ordinary free functions. Below is the [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/xhEM7oYs1) where I've shown how to achieve what you want:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  static void bar(const Args&... args)
  {
    /* code */ 
  }
};

class Example
{
public:
  
 
    template< typename... Param,typename Ret, typename... Args>  
    //no need to use any class type here as we have static member function which is treated as ordinary free function
    void doStuff(Ret (*ptrFunc)(const Param&... param),const Args&... args)

    {

    }
};

class SomeThing
{
public:
  Example ex {};

  template<typename... Args>
  void someFunc(const Args&... args)
  {
    ex.doStuff(&Foo::bar<Args...>,args...);    
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomeThing sc {};
  sc.someFunc("Some ", "Arguments ", "Here"); 
  
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things are unclear. For example, why would you want to pass a template along with arguments that you will use to instantiate it, rather than directly passing the instantiation. However, I suppose this is due to simplification and what you want is to have a static member template as argument of another template.

To my knowledge, this is not possible. At least not directly.

What you can do is use a template template argument to pass a type. A static method of that template can forward to the static method of `Foo`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  static void bar(const Args&... args)
  {
  }
};

template <typename ...Args>
struct helper {
    static void bar(const Args&...args){
        Foo::bar(args...);
    }
};


template<template<typename...> typename M,typename...Args>
void doStuff(const Args&... args) {
    M<Args...>::bar(args...);
}


int main() {
    doStuff<helper,int>(42);
}
```

Depending on what you actually need, helper could be parametrized on a type so you could use it also for other types that have a `bar` static mehtod. However, for other types that have a static method of different name we are back to square one, you would need another helper.

If you just want to pass a callable to `doStuff` perhaps it does not have to be more complicated than this:

```
 template <typename F, typename Args...>
 void doStuff(F f,const Args&...args) { F(args...); }
 // (no perfect forwarding as in your code and in the code above)

 int main() { 
      doStuff([](int a) { Foo::bar(a); },42);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have too much time but here is a quick shot on how to pass a member function pointer into a function template to select a "callback" to process the data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    template<class ... Q>
    void x(Q&&... q)    
    {
        std::cout << "A::x\n";
    }
    template<class ... R>
    void y(R&&... r)    
    {
        std::cout << "A::y\n";
    }
    template<class F, class ... W>
    void do_stuff(F&& f, W&&... w)  
    {
        std::cout << "A::do_stuff\n";
        (this->*f)(std::forward<W>(w)...);
    }
};

class B
{
public:

  A a{};

  template<typename... Args>
  void bar(Args&&... args)
  {
    a.do_stuff(&A::x<Args...>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    a.do_stuff(&A::y<Args...>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

int main()
{
  B b{};
  b.bar(1, "yes");
}
```